# Access data from Model in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

I have a model for displaying a list of latest articles, and I would like to be able to define how many articles are displayed. I have created a property called `DisplayNumberOfPressArticles` and I would like to be able to access the value of this property from my controller.

Here is the model:

```
using Site.Helpers.Selections;
using Site.Models.Blocks.Data;
using EPiServer.DataAnnotations;
using EPiServer.Shell.ObjectEditing;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Site.Models.Blocks
{
    [SiteContentType(GUID = "884202C2-61F1-4DF5-85A7-DC3D4E493F59")]
    [SiteImageUrl]
    public class LastArticlesTeaserBlock : SiteBlockData, PressOverviewData, ISpaceableData
    {
        [CultureSpecific]
        public virtual string Heading { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 1000)]
        public virtual int DisplayNumberOfPressArticles { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my controller, I would like to take the value of `DisplayNumberOfPressArticles` as a limit for the .Take() query:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Site.Models.Blocks;
using EPiServer.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Site.Models.Pages;
using Site.Models.ViewModels;
using EPiServer.Find;
using EPiServer.Find.Api;
using EPiServer.Find.Cms;
using EPiServer.Find.Framework;
using EPiServer.Logging;
using ILogger = EPiServer.Logging.ILogger;
using EPiServer.Globalization;

namespace Site.Controllers
{
    public class LastArticlesTeaserBlockController : BlockController<LastArticlesTeaserBlock>
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetLogger();
        public override ActionResult Index(LastArticlesTeaserBlock currentContent)
        {
            var model = new LastArticlesTeaserViewModel
            {
                Headline = currentContent.Heading,
                ArticlePages = GetArticlePages(),
                PaddingTop = currentContent.PaddingTop,
                PaddingBottom = currentContent.PaddingBottom
            };

            return PartialView(model);
        }

        private List<PressDetailsPage> GetArticlePages()
        {
            List<PressDetailsPage> result = new List<PressDetailsPage>();

            IClient findClient = SearchClient.Instance;
            var search = findClient.Search<PressDetailsPage>();

            search = search
                .Filter(sp => sp.IsDeleted.Match(false)).PublishedInCurrentLanguage()
                .Filter(sp => sp.Headline.Exists() | sp.Description.Exists())
                .Filter(sp => sp.Language.Name.Match(ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture.Name))
                .OrderByDescending(sp => sp.PublishDate, SortMissing.Last)
                .Take(??);

            try
            {
                var searchResult = search.GetContentResult();

                result.AddRange(searchResult);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                Logger.Error(e.ToString());
            }

            return result;

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the newbie question, but everything I have tried hasn't worked so far. I thought I could access the model by using `.Take(LastArticlesTeaserBlock.DisplayNumberOfPressArticles);`

Comment: You goto pass the `currentContent.DisplayNumberOfPressArticles` to the `GetArticlePages` method like Ted sais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing your signature to something like `GetArticlePages(int maxCount)` and then invoking it like `ArticlePages = GetArticlePages(currentContent.DisplayNumberOfPressArticles)` in your `Index` method?

Comment: Thank you, such a logical approach. Worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SearchClient` class looks like a *custom* implementation and hard to tell if the bug is there.

**Option 1:**
Something like -- `db.ArticleSet.OrderByDescending(t => t.Articles.Count).Take(10);`

---

**Option 2:**
Or a more direct query.

Make life easier and break it down in *two parts* firs the query, they execution, then put it back together if you want.

Step 1

```
var articlesQuery = from x in Articles..
                  where x.IsDeleted == true ....
```

Step 2

```
var limitedArticlesQuery  = articlesQuery.Take(25);
```

From client size send a `int pageSize`

```
var pagedProductQuery = articlesQuery.Skip(10 * pageSize).Take(10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the main point is that I need to use the value of the property DisplayNumberOfPressArticles from the Model as the value for .Take(). The idea is to allow the editors so select how many press articles are fetched and displayed.